# Why is this solution to $x^3+3x^2-8 = 0$ wrong?

Tags: algebra-precalculus

I'm still a beginner so please bear with me.
\begin{align}
x^3+3x^2-8 &= 0 \\
x^3+3x^2 &= 8 \\
x^2(x+3) &= 8 \\
x^2 &= 8 \\
x+3 &= 8 \\
x = \pm\sqrt{8}, &\quad x=5
\end{align}
However none of these are solutions for the cubic, I'm unsure what went wrong or why this method is false... And how would I go about solving this algebraically without an approximation method?

Comment: This is not zero product property. If $ab=0$, then $a=0$ or $b=0$

Comment: You can’t conclude $x^2=8$ or $x+3=8$ from $x^2(x+3)=8$.  To see why, can you solve $y(y+2)=8$?

Comment: Why not? Genuinely clueless. @J.W.Tanner

Comment: If $x(x+1)=6$, does $x=6$ or $x+1=6$?  Only when the right-hand side is $0$ can you work like this.

Comment: The principle that you’re thinking of is that if a product is *zero*, then one of the factors  must be zero. It simply *does not apply* to products that are nonzero.

Comment: Let $u=\frac1x$, then you get the  equation $8u^3-3u-1=0$ (this is possible because $x=0$ is clearly not a solution). Then you can use the fact that this is a depressed cubic and use Cardano's method: https://brilliant.org/wiki/cardano-method/.

Comment: Oh God.. I feel so stupid. Yes I can see what you all mean now. Thank you.

Comment: @Belal: If $ab = 8$, that doesn't tell you what either factor is.  It could be $2 \times 4$, $1 \times 8$, or even $\sqrt{2} \times 4\sqrt{2}$.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

For real numbers, $rs = 0$ implies that either $r=0$ or $s=0$ or both. This is why we factor a polynomial, *once it's set equal to zero.* This lovely property is not true for products that equal any other number.

Here's an easy counterexample, and you can come up with others yourself. Say $r=3$ and $s=4$, so $rs = 12$. Clearly, neither $r$ nor $s$ is $12$.

---

Solving the cubic polynomial equation has a rich history going back millennia. Some of that history, including some methods of solution, are recounted on the [wiki page](https://www.wikiwand.com/en/Cubic_equation). The wonderful *Mathologer* channel has [a video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=N-KXStupwsc) on a well-known method for solving the cubic that you might enjoy.

It's notable that we can't solve the general cubic using compass and straightedge (the tools of classical geometric constructions), but it can be solved using other more general tools, e.g. [neusis construction](https://www.wikiwand.com/en/Neusis_construction), essentially, replacing a straightedge with a marked straightedge ruler.

Answer (score 2):

Substituting $x=y-1$ into the original equation yields a new equation

$y^3-3y-6=0$, or

$y^3+py+q=0$, where $p=-3$ and $q=-6$.

This equation has a real root

$y_r=\sqrt[3]{-\frac{q}{2}+\sqrt{(\frac{q}{2})^2+(\frac{p}{3})^3}}+\sqrt[3]{-\frac{q}{2}-\sqrt{(\frac{q}{2})^2+(\frac{p}{3})^3}}$.

With $p=-3$ and $q=-6$, $y_r=\sqrt[3]{3+\sqrt{8}}+\sqrt[3]{3-\sqrt{8}}\approx 2.3553$.

Finally, the real solution of $x$ is $x_r=y_r-1\approx 1.3553$.

Comment: That answers the second part of my question, thank you!